# It's possible to add a logo to TopName in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, title, graphical-logo

Years ago I had a full domain/host in wordpress and I could change what I want. But now I'm exploring free wordpress host. Every existing blog theme has a title in the page top, but I wanted to put a tiny logo before that, is it possible in freehost wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already answered you a question about Wordpress. I think here you won't get any clear answer as in stackexchange for "wordpressers". Try here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

As for your question, I think it's not possible to do it.

Glad to help